# How to convert Array of string to List of string in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

> How to add a string item to the list in react js.
> sample Code:

```
const value1="Book";
const value2="Pen";
const value3="Note";

const arrayValue=[];
arrayValue.push(value1);
arrayValue.push(value2);
arrayValue.push(value3);
console.log(arrayValue);

Output is : ["Book","Pen","Note"];
expected output is : object:{[0]."Book",[1]."Pen",[2]."Note"}
```

Comment: Why is that your expected output?


You have an array so if you console.log the array you will get an array as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object instead of array like this

```
const arrayValue={};
arrayValue['1'] = value1;
// Same for the other values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const value1="Book";
const value2="Pen";
const value3="Note";

const arrayValue=[];
arrayValue.push(value1);
arrayValue.push(value2);
arrayValue.push(value3);
console.log(arrayValue);
const newObj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arrayValue.length; i++) {
  newObj[i] = arrayValue[i]
}
console.log(newObj)
```

This is what is logged

```
["Book", "Pen", "Note"]
[object Object] {
  0: "Book",
  1: "Pen",
  2: "Note"
}
```

```
const value2="Pen";
const value3="Note";

const arrayValue=[];
arrayValue.push(value1);
arrayValue.push(value2);
arrayValue.push(value3);
console.log(arrayValue);
const newObj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arrayValue.length; i++) {
  let string = `[${i.toString()}]`
  newObj[string] = arrayValue[i]
}
console.log(newObj)
```

This is Logged

```
["Book", "Pen", "Note"]
[object Object] {
  [0]: "Book",
  [1]: "Pen",
  [2]: "Note"
}
```

Comment: or just make it an object without ever making it an array like Sahil said.

Comment: ok. I will try this.

Comment: I need to pass the array value to List<string>. How to convert the array value in List<string>

Comment: I don't think I follow what you are trying to do, are you trying to make a 'Linked List' in Javascript?

Comment: const newObj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < arrayValue.length; i++) {
  newObj[i] = arrayValue[i]
} This code not working. It return single array. My expected output is index 0="Book", 1="Pen", 2="Note"

Comment: The code I wrote prints both the array and the object.

Comment: I shared my CodeSandbox Link https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-night-mym09?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Output is: {0: "Book", 1: "Pen", 2: "Note"}
0: "Book"
1: "Pen"
2: "Note"

Comment: My expected output is: {[0]:"Book",[1]:"Pen",[2]."Note"}

Comment: Is there a reason you want brackets around the keys in the object?  I guess inside the loop you could turn the number into a string and put it inside brackets.  I will add edit to do that.

Comment: I need to convert and pass an array of strings as a list of strings in HttpGet request params. In HTTP get request params. It comes with a single object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {}
for (var i in arrayValue){
    obj[i] = arrayValue[i];
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your "expected output" is an object.
This has nothing to do with react though...

Try this:

```js
list = ["1", "2", "3"];
object = {};

for(x=0; x < list.length; x++){
  object[x] = list[x];
}
console.log(object)
```